# How to prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(xy)}{|x-y|}$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove this $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(xy)}{|x-y|}$ does not exist. For my calculus class. I know that I have to show that there at least two paths that lead me to different limits but I can't come up with them... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go along the axis the limit will be 0.
Just try with $\alpha(t)=(t,0)$.

$(f \circ \alpha)(t)= \frac{0}{|t|}$ if you take the limit of this it will be clearly $0$.

Then you can try with a series such as $p_n=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1})$ this series goes to $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity. If you make the composition with $f$ you will end up with the following:

$$(f \circ p_n)(n)=\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n(n+1)})}{|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}|}$$

Work around this, you'll see that the limit of this one is different to $0$

Answer (score 4):

Path 1: $y=0$

Path 2: $y=x-x^2$

Comment: here in 2nd path  $\frac{\sin(x^3-x^2)}{x^2}$ $\approx \frac{x^3-x^2}{x^2}$ that will give $1$ , am i right?